# What is MDO With VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

What is MDO? Moreover, if I want to do VBA with MDO, what does that mean?

Comment: Could you be more specific about mdo? Any link or reference?

Comment: MDO can stand for a lot of things. Your question needs context, where did you see it? How was is used?

Comment: there's some analytical group in northrop grummen and they need someone that is good with MDO with vba

Comment: If you don't know what it is, you're obviously not good at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps http://www.vivaceproject.com/content/advanced/mdo_frame_exec.pdf

MDO Multidisciplinary Design and Optimisation